# flexbox align child container items?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the below flex items. I want to align the HeaderContainer items.

I am using margin-top and margin-left, margin-right in btnCss class to align the items.

I want the Header **Title to be in center and button to top right with some margins**.

Is it possible to achieve this without margin-top, left, right?

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="parentContainer">

    <div class ="headerContainer">
     <div  class="headerTitle"> 
        <h2> Header Title Here </h2> 
      </div>
      <div class="btnCss">
        <button> Click Me </button   
      </div>
     </div>

    </div>
    <div>

      <div>

      <p> laksjdfklsadfjalskdjfklsadjfklsajfkl </p>
            <p> laksjdfklsadfjalskdjfklsadjfklsajfkl </p>

            <p> laksjdfklsadfjalskdjfklsadjfklsajfkl </p>
      <p> laksjdfklsadfjalskdjfklsadjfklsajfkl </p>

            <p> laksjdfklsadfjalskdjfklsadjfklsajfkl </p>
      <p> laksjdfklsadfjalskdjfklsadjfklsajfkl </p>

       </div>



  </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Below is the CSS:

```
.parentContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.headerContainer {
  width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.btnCss {
  margin-top: 23px;
  margin-left: 280px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `justify-content: space-between;`

```
.headerContainer {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve it instead of using margins you can use position relative to the viewports that is top, bottom, left, right properties to position the element.

```css
.parentContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.btnCss {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="parentContainer">

    <div class ="headerContainer">
     <div  class="headerTitle"> 
        <h2> Header Title Here </h2> 
      </div>
      <div class="btnCss">
        <button> Click Me </button   
      </div>
     </div>

    </div>
    <div>

      <div>

      <p> laksjdfklsadfjalskdjfklsadjfklsajfkl </p>
            <p> laksjdfklsadfjalskdjfklsadjfklsajfkl </p>

            <p> laksjdfklsadfjalskdjfklsadjfklsajfkl </p>
      <p> laksjdfklsadfjalskdjfklsadjfklsajfkl </p>

            <p> laksjdfklsadfjalskdjfklsadjfklsajfkl </p>
      <p> laksjdfklsadfjalskdjfklsadjfklsajfkl </p>

       </div>



  </div>



</body>
</html>
```